# Building dependency graph of variables in scala

Tags: scala, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, dependency-graph

I have a sequence of variables of type x. Type x is defined as

```
(a: Int, b: Set[Int])
```

Some variables have overlapping values for b. For example, variables

```
p = (1, Set(1, 2, 3)) 
q = (5, Set (3, 4, 5))
r = (10, Set(9, 10))
```

The notion of dependency is that if variables have overlapping values of `b`, this indicates that they are dependent (for this example, `p` and `q` are dependent, `r` is independent). I want to make a dependency graph where the variables which are dependent has an edge and the independent variables are single nodes. How can I achieve this in Scala?

Comment: Is it probability theory or is it register allocation, or is it something entirely different? Are you sure that you don't want to call it "interference"?

Comment: There are many possible answers, from one-sentence "use container X and algorithm Y" to something that contains a comprehensive Scala tutorial and relevant topics from graph theiry and computer science. What kind of answer do you expect? Here's one of the first kind: build a reverse map `Map[Int, Set[Var]]` and connect all variables in each separate set. (Ints come from 'b').